# How to convert an anonymous function with multiple arguments into an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, function

I am able to assign the value of an anonymous function to a variable like this:

```
let x = function(y,z) { return y + z }(1,2);
```

The resulting value of x is 3.
Following the guide at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions the equivalent using arrow functions should be this I think.

```
let x = (y = 1, z = 2) => { return y + z };
```

However the value of x in this case becomes NaN. Why is that?

Comment: `x` becomes the function. actually there is no call of the function.

Comment: `let x = function(y,z) { return y + z }(1,2)` x isn't a function, it's just 3.. the arrow solution would be `let x =((y,z) => y + z)(1,2)`

Comment: [Your code should not be returning NaN](https://jsfiddle.net/Lstr5xmp/).

Comment: `let x = (y = 1, z = 2) => y + z; console.log(x(3))` using the defaults

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged this with svelte?

Comment: I am doing this in svelte, I don't know if svelte is causing things to be different.

Answer (score 1):

`let x = (y = 1, z = 2) => { return y + z }` assigns the *function* to the variable, *not* its call. To assign the function call to a variable first you need to call it. So, arrow function equivalent of `let y = function(y,z) { return y + z }(1,2);` would be:

```js
let x = ((y = 1, z = 2) => { return y + z })()
// or
let x2 = ((y, z) => { return y + z })(1,2)
// or
let x3 = ((y = 1, z = 2) => (y + z))()
// or
let x4 = ((y, z) => (y + z))(1,2)

let y = function(y,z) { return y + z }(1,2);

console.log(x)
console.log(x2)
console.log(x3)
console.log(x4)
console.log(y)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```